# How to check if coroutines are using the same context?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have two Coroutines and I want to check if they are running in the same context/Dispatcher. This is a simplified version of my problem, but the answer will apply to the thing I am doing:

```
@Test
fun test() {
   val io = runBlocking(Dispatcher.IO) {
       coroutineContext
   }
   val nonIo = runBlocking() {
       coroutineContext
   }
   assertNotEquals(io, nonIo)
}
```

However, this is a bad test because I am simply comparing two distinct objects. I want to compare if they use `Dispatcher.IO` or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean to ask if the the coroutines use the same Dispatcher, right? A dispatcher is just one piece of a CoroutineContext. You can use the `get` function of a CoroutineContext with the key `ContinuationInterceptor` to retrieve the Dispatcher.

```
val io = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor]
}
val nonIo = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor]
}
assertNotEquals(io, nonIo)
```